# Верстка в asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Всем привет. Сделал верстку шаблона в html странице. Теперь хочу создать aspx страницу с этим шаблоном. А как то что я сверстал перенести на aspx страницу?

Comment: ``Ctrl+C => Ctrl+V``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Страница aspx верстается с помощью html, если Вы работаете с ней в Visual Studio, переключитесь в режим Source (или Split).